# Parent path issue in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am facing a file not found issue while setting up my classic asp website in windows 7 which has iis 7.5 in it. It was working perfectly fine in windows xp which had iis 5, I guess.

When I am trying to access the file header.asp (which is located in "test\include_files\header.asp") from "test\manager\team.asp" it tries to look for the header.asp in the path "test\manager\include_files\header.asp" whereas it should look into "test\include_files\header.asp".

In the file team.asp, this is how I am calling the file:
`<!-- #include file="../include_files/header.asp" -->`

I understand in IIS 6 and above the parent path is not enabled by default and I have enabled it through IIS Manager but still no luck. I searched the Internet and also this site, and the only thing that needs to be done it seems is to enable the parent path which I have already done. I also tried by typing in the full path as in: "test\include_files\header.asp" but no luck!

Please advise what else needs to be done to have it working.
Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: try using the ***virtual*** keyword. So _<!-- #include virtual=_ instead of _<!-- #include file=_

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried both the following (actual and relative paths) but still no luck. I am still getting the same error which is "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Error Code 0x80070002"

1. <!-- #include file="..\include_files\header.asp" -->
2. <!-- #include virtual="test/include_files/header.asp" -->

Just to add more information if it helps, this 'test' folder is in the "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" path.

Comment: Start with forward slash, like this <!-- #include virtual="/test/include_files/header.asp" -->

Answer (score 0):

When you use `include file`, you must refer to the file as drive path, not web path.

So change your `/` to `\`, like this:

```
<!--#include file="..\include_files\header.asp"-->
```

If you would like to do `include virtual` then you can use `/` instead of `\`.

```
<!--#include virtual="../include_files/header.asp"-->
```

So to resolve your issue, change the `\` to `/` or change from `include file` to `include virtual`